# document.getElementById() not working as intended with multiple ids

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have an issue with document.getElementById(). Basically I have different forms each one with a different id and I'm using a bit of Javascript to replace some classes and add dinamically file name after upload.

That should be really easy, but I don't know why even if the ids are totally unique I get a weird behavior: whatever is the form in which I submit a file javascript will apply changes always on the first of them.

```js
function spinnerLoad(){

  document.getElementById('file-name[[${id}]]').textContent = this.files[0].name;
  
  document.getElementById('spinner[[${id}]]').classList.replace('fas', 'spinner-border');
  document.getElementById('spinner[[${id}]]').classList.replace('fa-file-upload', 'spinner-border-sm');
  document.getElementById('uploadForm[[${id}]]').submit()

}
```

```css
/*I'm using Bootstrap for my styling rules*/
```

```html
/*${id} variable is server-side and it's there to make unique each form, I'm using Thymeleaf template engine*/
<form th:id="'uploadForm'+${id}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/upload/{id} (id=${id})}">
  <label for="file-upload" class="btn btn-outline-success">
  <span th:id="'spinner'+${id}" class="fas fa-file-upload"></span> <b>Upload file:</b> <i th:id="'file-name'+${id}">No file selected</i>
  </label>
  <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="multipartFile"  accept="application/pdf" style="display: none" th:onchange="spinnerLoad()"/>
</form>
```

I googled the problem but I didn't manage to find a specific answer to my issue, so that's why I'm here bothering you.

I hope someone can help my figure this out, thank you.

Comment: The code you posted works fine. Are you trying to execute it before the actual elements have been rendered to the page? You said _"I tried to trigger that code onload, on change of an input value but it always acts the same way."_ but I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that

Comment: Tested your code, it's working, can you elaborate what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: You are missing the css, but still the code works properly

Comment: Hi @Gu160 I try your code and it's working fine here is a code example: https://jsfiddle.net/rk02qpb5/  I just applied a red border on the clicked button. Can you share the origin code, So that I can look at it?

Comment: Thank you for all your replies, actually that was just a little representative example of my issue and not exactly what I'm trying to do in my code. I will upload the actual code updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

You get a lot of repeating code and that can be hard to maintain. Here I placed the event listener on the the parent `<div>` to all the buttons. Then I need to test if is a button. And there is no need for an id for each button.

Actually, if you are just replacing a class name you don't even need to do the test (`if()`), because `replace()` will only do the replacement when the old value is present. This should be fine:

```
buttons.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.classList.replace('btn-success', 'btn-danger');
});
```

But here is the full example with the test:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementById('buttons');

buttons.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
    e.target.classList.replace('btn-success', 'btn-danger');
  }
});
```

```css
.btn-success {
  background-color: green;
}

.btn-danger {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="btn-success">Button 1</button>
  <button class="btn-success">Button 2</button>
  <button class="btn-success">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the css that would make this work, but otherwise your example is functional.  However, it can be done more simply by working on the buttons as a class instead of individually.

```js
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
var addDanger = function(){
  this.classList.replace('btn-success', 'btn-danger')
};

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', addDanger, false);
};
```

```css
.btn {height:20px; width: 50px;}
.btn-success {background-color:green}
.btn-danger {background-color:red}
```

```html
<button id="btn1" class="btn btn-success"></button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn btn-success"></button>
<button id="btn3" class="btn btn-success"></button>
```